# Rails - How to handle record create with has_many association error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am running into a problem when trying to handle a `#create` request on a model with a `has_many` association where one of the passed in IDs does not belong to an existing record.

Test request:

```
post authors_path, params: { book_ids: [-1] }
```

Controller method:

```
def create
  @author= Author.create params
end
```

Model:

```
class Author
  has_many :books
end
```

This results in an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error being raised.

The problem is as follows:

I am already rescuing from an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error and responding with `404 Record Not Found` in my `ApplicationController` because such an error typically arises when a user is attempting to `GET`, `PATCH`, `PUT`, or `DELETE` a record that does not exist, e.g., `get author_path(-1)`. I would prefer to avoid moving the `rescue` clause onto the `#show`, `#create`, etc methods because I have a lot of controllers, resulting in a lot of duplicate code.

I want to keep my record and association creations atomic and this seems to be the best way to do it, but I also want to respond with a `400 Bad Request` when the situation described above occurs. What would be the best way to handle such a situation?

**UPDATE**

After some more research, I wrote a quick custom validation that validates a record exists for all passed in `book_ids`

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord  
  validate :books_exist  

  def books_exist  
    return if book_ids.blank?  
    Book.find book_ids
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e  
    errors.add e.message  
  end  
end
```

This doesn't seem to work though as even instantiating a new `Author` instance without saving it to the database throws an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error:

```
> Author.new(association_ids: [-1])
  Book Load (2.3ms) SELECT `books`.* FROM `books` WHERE `books`.`id` = -1
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Book with 'id'=[-1]
  from ...
```

The issue seems to be that `ActiveRecord` attempts to find a record for the passed in `book_id` before any validation occurs. Is there any way to rescue this error? It seems like there's not much of a workaround for this particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two solutions that were suggest to me outside of StackOverflow are as follows:

1. Rescue the error in each controller action

   ```
   class AuthorsController
     def create
       @author = Author.create(params)
       render json: @author
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
       render json_error_message
     end
   end
   ```
2. Create a generic action in the `ApplicationController`

   ```
   class ApplicationController
     def create(model)
       instance_variable_set("@#(model.class.name}", model.create(params)
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
       render json_error_message
     end
   end

   class AuthorsController
     def create
       super(Author)
     end
   end
   ```